# Has anyone used Ant4Eclipse with Project Lombok?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, lombok

Has anyone successfully used Ant4Eclipse (http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) in combination with Project Lombok (http://projectlombok.org/)?

Lombok provides annotations for removing boilerplate code; however, it doesn't appear to play nicely with Ant4Eclipse (headless compilation of Eclipse projects).  For instance, the following Lombok sample compiles fine in Eclipse and javac:

```
import lombok.Getter;
public class LombokTest {
  private @Getter String foo; 
  public LombokTest() {
    String s = this.getFoo();
  }
}
```

But compiling with Ant4Eclipse's `<buildJdtProject>` yields the following:

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file
[javac] ----------
[javac] 1. WARNING in C:\dev\Java\workspace\LombokTest\src\LombokTest.java (at line 4)
[javac]     private @Getter String foo;
[javac]                            ^^^
[javac] The field LombokTest.foo is never read locally
[javac] ----------
[javac] 2. ERROR in C:\dev\Java\workspace\LombokTest\src\LombokTest.java (at line 8)
[javac]             String s = this.getFoo();
[javac]                             ^^^^^^
[javac] The method getFoo() is undefined for the type LombokTest
[javac] ----------
```

Has anyone successfully used these libraries together?

Thanks!

**Edit**: [sample project](http://www.whitelite.net/LombokTest.zip) demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually managed to compile a lombok project with ant4eclipse by delomboking the project first with

```
<delombok verbose="true"; encoding="UTF-8" 
    to="${workspaceDirectory}/myproject/src" 
    from="${workspaceDirectory}/myproject/src-original" />
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC in order to use Lombok in Eclipse, there's a parameter required at start-up to introduce Lombok's Java Agent into the JDT compile process. This is normally specified in the `eclipse.ini` file. If Ant4Eclipse does not also make use of those parameters (I don't see why it would) you may have to specify the `-javaagent:lombok.jar` parameter for that too.

DISCLAIMER: this is only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Supplied project does not compile out of the box with Eclipse Java EE 3.5.2 using Java 6.  The errors in Eclipse are the same as those given by ant4eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted: you need to install Lombok into Eclipse first (by double-clicking lib/lombok/lombok.jar).

Comment: You mean add lombok.jar to build path?

Comment: No, lombok needs to hook into Eclipse. It uses a java agent to do that. If you download lombok.jar and run java -jar lombok.jar you'll get an installer screen, including a button that explains how it will modify your Eclipse installation. And yes, you also have to add it to the build path.

Comment: So the problem is that you need to hook lombok into your ant4eclipse configuration too.  What does the lombok documentation say about using from within ant?

Comment: For ant and javac, you just need to make sure it's on the classpath of the compiler.